# L'articolo prima di una proposizione sostantiva: "studio del come devono..."

Tags: grammar, articles

Ho appena cominciato a leggere *I Malavoglia* e la prima frase è come segue:

> Questo racconto è lo studio sincero e spassionato **del** come devono nascere e svilupparsi nelle più umili condizioni le primi irrequietudini pel benessere;

So (e ce ne sono anche molte [spiegazioni in Internet](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/infinito-sostantivato_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)) che certi verbi all'infinito, quando hanno la funzione di sostantivi, devono essere preceduti da un articolo. Però, qui non c'è un verbo all'infinito ma una proposizione finita. Capisco il significato della frase ma io avrei detto invece:

> Questo racconto è lo studio sincero e spassionato **di** come devono nascere e svilupparsi nelle più umili condizioni le primi irrequietudini pel benessere;

È correcta anche quest'ultima frase, oppure avrei avuto torto se avessi omesso l'articolo? Perché mette il Verga l'articolo, se non c'è nessun verbo all'infinito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sì, la tua frase è corretta. La scelta di Verga di usare *del* invece che *di* è altrettanto corretta grammaticalmente, ma leggermente più letteraria e anche in parte attribuibile allo stile di Verga.

Non bisogna dimenticare, inoltre, che spesso espressioni del genere subiscono, con il tempo, un declino, a favore di altre più colloquiali. Una ricerca comparata su [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=del%20come%2C%20di%20come&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdel%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdel%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDel%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdel%20Come%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdi%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdi%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdi%20Come%3B%2Cc0) mostra come nei decenni "di come" sia finito per prevalere nei testi scritti (se non altro in quelli archiviati da Google).

[image]

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie Charo :)